# Is there a way to extract information from shadow-root on a Website?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am setting up code to check the reputation of any URL E.g. http://go.mobisla.com/ on Website "https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/url"

First, the very basic thing I am doing is to extract all the Website contents using BeautifulSoup but seems the information I am looking for is in shadow-root(open) -- div.detections and span.individual-detection.

Example Copied Element from Webpage results:

No engines detected this URL

I am new to Python, wondering if you can share the best way to extract the information

Tried requests.get() function but it doesn't give the required information

```
import requests
import os,sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url_check = "deloplen.com:443"
url = "https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/url"
req  = requests.get(url + url_str)
html = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Expect to see "2 engines detected this URL" along with Detection Example: Dr. Web Malicious

Comment: You're better off using their API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use their website, it'll only return a loading screen for VirusTotal, as this isn't the proper way.

What Shows Up: [image]

Instead, what you're supposed to do is use their public API to make requests. However, you'll have to make an account to obtain a Public API Key.

You can use this code which is able to retrieve JSON info about the link. However, you'll have to fill in the API KEY with yours.

```
import requests, json

user_api_key = "<api key>"
resource = "deloplen.com:443"

# feel free to remove this, just makes it look nicer
def pp_json(json_thing, sort=True, indents=4):
    if type(json_thing) is str:
        print(json.dumps(json.loads(json_thing), sort_keys=sort, indent=indents))
    else:
        print(json.dumps(json_thing, sort_keys=sort, indent=indents))
        return None

response = requests.get("https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report?apikey=" + user_api_key + "&resource=" + resource)

json_response = response.json()

pretty_json = pp_json(json_response)

print(pretty_json)
```

If you want to learn more about the API, you can use their [documentation](https://developers.virustotal.com/).

Comment: it's working..one thing what would be the best way to grab specifically                  "positives": 2 along with the true ones with their "result"                                                                                                                                                           "positives": 2,<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    "resource": "cdn.ibbyu85u.com:80",                                                                                                             "Kaspersky": {
            "detected": true,  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            "result": "malware site" <<<<<<<<<<<

Comment: You'll want to parse it through JSON @Gary

Comment: @Axium..Thanks I tried but no luck.. Could you please share an example snippet code to extract below:                                                                                                                     "Kaspersky": {
            "detected": true,
            "result": "malware site"