# How to detect a red flag, phishing or malicious site with python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to detect malicious sites using python.

Now, I've tried using `requests` module to get the contents of a website, then would search for `malicious words` in it. But, I didn't get it to work.

[image: here example images of red page]

this my all code : [link code](https://pastebin.com/t43WqW8U)

```
req_check = requests.get(url)

    if 'malicious words' in req_check.content:
        print ('[Your Site Detect Red Page]   ===>   '+url)
    else:
        print ('[Your Site Not Detect Red Page]   ===>   '+url)
```

Comment: My answer here could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57299979/7363404

Comment: what do you get in `req_check.content` ? Browser may block url and display red page with message - it is not send from server but displayed by function built-in in browser so you can't get it with requests or urllib. You would have to send url to portal which can check url - like virustotal.com

Comment: See [virustotal's API](https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002146469-API-scripts) to use it in Python.

Comment: This doesn't work because `req_check.content` just doesn't have your desired string in it. Could you give us the output of `req_check.content`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would comment that your indentation might be messed where there is other code. Otherwise, it should work flawlessly.

### Edit 2

It appeared that OP was after a way to detect malicious sites in python. This is a documentation from [totalvirus](https://developers.virustotal.com/reference#url-scan) explaining how to leverage their `APIs`.

Now to give you a working example, this will print a list of engines reporting positive:

```
import requests


apikey = '<api_key>'

def main():
    scan_url('https://friborgerforbundet.no/')

def scan_url(url):
    params = {'apikey': apikey, 'url': url}
    response = requests.post('https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/scan', data=params)
    scan_id = response.json()['scan_id']
    report_params = {'apikey': apikey, 'resource': scan_id}
    report_response = requests.get('https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report', params=report_params)
    scans = report_response.json()['scans']

    positive_sites = []
    for key, value in scans.items():
        if value['detected'] == True:
            positive_sites.append(key)

    print(positive_sites)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: if detect result just `[]` ?

Comment: @StuartLee this means negative; i.e the website is not detected by any engine.

Comment: @StuartLee If this answer helped, will you pls mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're using the `requests` library wrong.

In your code, you essentially only get the HTML of the virus site (line of code: `req_check = requests.get(url, verify=False)` and `if 'example for detect ' in req_check.content:`{source: https://pastebin.com/6x24SN6v})

In Chrome, the browser runs through a database of known virus links (its more complicated than this) and sees if the link is safe. However, the `requests` library **does not** do this. Instead, you're better off using their API. If you want to see how the API can be used in conjunction with `requests`, you can see my answer on another question: [Is there a way to extract information from shadow-root on a Website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281787/is-there-a-way-to-extract-information-from-shadow-root-on-a-website/57299979#57299979)

Sidenote, the `redage()` is never called?

Answer (score -1):

Tell the user to enter a website, then use selenium or something to upload the url to virustotal.com

Comment: This is not a complete answer.